# Set text if spinner selected

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a schedule program, in the first spinner I select the specialty, in the second group, I need that when the group is selected in the TextView the schedule of this group is displayed. I can not find information how to do it.

```
/dd menu
        sp_parent=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp_child =findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        // ============= Array List proffesions ============
        arrayList_parent=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList_parent.add("Облік і оподаткування"); arrayList_parent.add("Харчові технології"); arrayList_parent.add("Готельно-ресторанна справа");
        arrayList_parent.add("Право"); arrayList_parent.add("Комп'ютерна інженерія");  arrayList_parent.add("Підприємництво, торгівля та біржова діяльність");
        arrayList_parent.add("Туризм"); arrayList_parent.add("Фінанси, банківська справа і страхування");

        arrayAdapter_parent=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_parent);
        sp_parent.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_parent);
```

[image]

```
sp_parent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                if(position==0){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_oblic );
                    String selected = (String) sp_child.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    schedule_text.setText(selected);

                }
                if(position==1){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_food_technology );
                    String selected = sp_child.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    schedule_text.setText(selected);
                }
                if(position==2){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_hotel );
                }
                if(position==3){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_law );
                }
                if(position==4){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_comp_genius );
                }
                if(position==5){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_businessman );
                }
                if(position==6){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_tourism );
                }
                if(position==7){
                    arrayAdapter_child=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_economy );
                }
                        sp_child.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_child);

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

}

```
This is my code
```